# core data NSManagedObject generated functions

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm having a problem understanding how to use my core data generated `NSManagedObject`.

Category.h:

```
@class Product;

@interface Category : NSManagedObject {
@private
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * mName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* mProduct;
@end
```

Category.m:

```
#import "Category.h"
#import "Product.h"

@implementation Category
@dynamic mName;
@dynamic mProduct;


- (void)addMProductObject:(Product *)value {    
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"mProduct" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"mProduct"] addObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"mProduct" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [changedObjects release];
}

- (void)removeMProductObject:(Product *)value {
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"mProduct" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"mProduct"] removeObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"mProduct" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [changedObjects release];
}

- (void)addMProduct:(NSSet *)value {    
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"mProduct" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:value];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"mProduct"] unionSet:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"mProduct" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:value];
}

- (void)removeMProduct:(NSSet *)value {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"mProduct" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:value];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"mProduct"] minusSet:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"mProduct" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:value];
}


@end
```

**How do I add a `Product` to a `Category`?**  By default, these functions(`- (void)addMProductObject:(Product *)value`, etc) aren't visible when i try this:

```
Product *product = (Product*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];;
...
Category *cat = (Category*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Category" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
...
[cat addMProductObject:product];
```

**warning: 'Category' may not respond to '-addMProductObject:'**

**Can i just declare these functions in `Category.h` so they are visible and use them normally?**

Before xcode 4(i think), these functions were declared in the .h file and i could use the without warnings.  I believe the functions looked a bit different too.  I am creating a new core data project and this is new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just declare them in the .h file.  I think there's a way to have Xcode put the declarations there automatically...

*Edit: Yup, you can just copy-and-paste the relationships from the model editor to your .h file.  [Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/creating_accessors.html)*

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `addMProductObject` is not defined in the .h file.
Because of that compiler thinks that it the Category class might not respond to it.

Also, note the following:

Are you using this with OS 10.7 SDK?
If yes, maybe even if it's LLVM compiler on iOS 5 beta, I didn't check that, the problem could be that:
`Category` is already taken as a name in the SDK.
In Lion SDK, the word `Category` is already defined in the SDK (since there are class categories).

Try changing class name to something else.

Comment: Thanks for the name-change suggestion.  I have made that change to eliminate any future name-clash problems.